# Does taking logs to supress hetroskedasticity only work for the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, logarithm, dependent-variable

I have been told that by logging variables in a regression that hetroskedasticity of errors can be reduced. Is this the case also if only my dependent variable is logged?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?  However, I'd say that, rather than transform data, you might want to look into different models that don't require homoscedasticity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking logs of positive variables other than the response cannot improve heteroskedasticity (it has no effect on the variance of the response) -- it will just stretch or squeeze different parts in the x-direction without changing the variances at those moved positions. However transformations of the predictors do change the shape of the relationship with the conditional mean of the response.

Taking logs of the response variable ("dependent variable") is on occasion useful for making the variance more nearly constant, but it's not the only consideration when dealing with heteroskedasticity.

In particular, if the form of the heteroskedasticity has the variance approximately proportional to the square of the mean -- which is fairly common with a few types of response variable -- then the log transformation will make the variance nearly constant. However, since it also changes the shape of the relationship, you may need to carefully consider the impact on the model. In some cases that may actually be useful, but in others it will not (e.g. it may help to linearize relationships and remove interactions, or on the other hand, sometimes it may induce curved relationships and bring in interactions that were not present on the untransformed data). Interpretation is sometimes trickier. There's also the problem in taking predictions back to the original scale - exponentiating a mean forecast on the log scale doesn't give you a mean on the original scale (and while there are adjustments that can be made to that forecast, there are several issues in doing so which people often fail to consider).

Even when you have the kind of variance relationship that the transformation workswell on, it may be better to instead consider a model that is heteroskedastic of that form; e.g. generalized linear models are one choice for specific types of heteroskedastic models, though there are other options. One nice thing about modelling the variable directly with a more suitable model is the lack of need to try to deal with expectation not being equivariant to nonlinear transformation (i.e. you can just interchange the order of transformation and expectation and keep things the same).